# Watir PageObject Indexed_Property not using string substitution

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

In a couple places, I'm creating an indexed_property, but when I call it, the index is always 1.

[image: example screenshot]

```
indexed_property(:team, [
  [:span, :team, {css: 'article#AssignTeams-Teams table tr:nth-child(%s) td:nth-child(1) span'}]
])
```

Implemented:

```
assign_teams_page.team[5].team_element
```

When I put a break point on it and make the call, the element's selector is:

> article#AssignTeams-Teams table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) span

it should be tr:nth-child(5) instead of tr:nth-child(1).  Why am I seeing this, how do I fix it?

Comment: Would you be able to put together an HTML page and full page object that reproduces the problem? I tried using the same indexed_property and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Finding an element isn't my issue, the %s isn't getting the correct number.  That shouldn't rely on the actual page, should it?

Comment: Sorry, I had not thought that comment out very thoroughly. You are probably right that the page does not matter. My point was just that we would benefit from having an isolated script that anyone could copy and execute to see the problem (at least I was not able to reproduce it from the current information).

Comment: There's nothing that I could reproduce that would be reasonably close to what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a current bug in page-object 1.0.2 that causes indexed properties to retain the definition of the first time you call them. So if you called:

```rb
assign_teams_page.team[1].team_element
assign_teams_page.team[5].team_element
```

It would be using the index 1 every time. There is a fix in place but not released yet. You can fix the issue by downgrading to page-object 1.0.0 or upgrading to 1.0.3 when it comes out.